# SVN ERROR : 'http://ipaddresshere:81/test': Could not resolve hostname ` The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: svn

Please help me regarding this problem. I configured the Apache and Subversion in the windows server 2008. It goes well, I can access the repository in the server using my browser.
In my local machine I have installed the TortoiseSVN, in the settings I enabled the proxy server, and in the proxy settings I put the orginal server address, the username and password and the port.
When I try to check-out I encountered the errors below:

Command: Checkout from http://ipaddresshere:81/test, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Error: OPTIONS of 'http://ipaddresshere:81/test': Could not resolve hostname `
Error: xx.xx.xxx.xxx': The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type
Error: was found.
Error:  (http://ipaddresshere:81)
Finished!:

I also tried to access the repository in my local machine using my browser http://ipaddress:portno/test but it says "Internet Explorer could not connect to ipaddress:portno"

What does it mean? I disabled my firewall and the problem still exist.
How to solve this problem?Please help me.

Comment: [This](http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&mid=34&ItemID=3&thread=301&pagenumber=1) may help. Or [this](http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=28).

Comment: Usually two reboots resolve issues like this.